# Multi datacenter - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, jboss

We have our DB2 database setup in 2 data centers in separate geographical locations. Each data center has a different instance of the database.

Our app which is setup in both data centers, invokes a VIP on Global Traffic Manager(GTM), which routes to the database nearest to it. Ideally, when app in data center 1 calls the DB VIP, it connects to the database within the data center.

Last night, we had a (network) issue at datacenter 1 database VIP so we disabled the data center 1 VIP, which ensured all the app calls to the database actually went to the database in data center 2.

Once the issue in data center 1 is fixed, we enabled the DB VIP for data center 1. But shortly after this, we started seeing below hibernate exceptions.

Appreciate any insight into this and how can we fix it?

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
                at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
                at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
                at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:191)

Comment: Did you restart data center 1 application?

Comment: Instead of showing the relevant hibernate configs for each of the dbs, you talked mainly about such networking things and ended up with just showing the exception. Btw, this could be related to the hibernate configs, for example when switching to another data center, the configuration should also be adjusted in the hibernate side (like the 'Session' object should also switch to adjust the new db name, host, etc.)